# How to immitate a "variable name" class like .join()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know how could i create a function that takes into account any string, like the .join(), where you can put any string before the dot to tell the computer that that string will be the one that will be between the joined parts.
For exemple, i would like to build a function that can take the string and repeat it many  times.
"tfg".function(5)
would give me: tfgtfgtfgtfgtfg

Comment: Are you asking how to add an instance method to the `str` class?

Comment: The `str` class already has that method. `str.__mul__(self, n)`. But don't call underscore named methods directly. You can just do `'tfg'*5`.

Comment: you can use something like forbiddenfruit to add arbitrary methods to builtins.... but i would strongly discourage doing so

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the `str` class and add that method:

```
class Mystr(str):
    def repeat(self, cnt):
        return self*cnt 

s=Mystr('tfg').repeat(5)

>>> s
'tfgtfgtfgtfgtfg'
```

But in this particular example, I am not sure that is easier than just directly:

```
>>> 'tfg'*5
'tfgtfgtfgtfgtfg'
```